# Calibrator on change event is not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below is my codes for my php and javascript event, however my Function()1 doesnt seem to be working.
Please help me. I got my previous js onchange event working , but not this one, everything is just the same.

**PHP**

```
<select id="Calibrator" name="Calibrator" onchange="myFunction1();">                               
    <option value="<?php echo $Calibrator; ?>"><?php echo $Calibrator; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php 
            if($Calibrator == 'Internal' || $Calibrator == NULL){
                echo "External";
            }else{
                echo "Internal";
            }
        ?>">
        <?php 
        if($Calibrator == 'Internal' ){ 
                echo "External";
            }else{
                echo "Internal";
            }
        ?></option>
            </select>
            <br>
        <label id="external" style="display:none">
        <label>External (FOR EXTERNAL)</label><label style='margin-left:112px'>: </label> 
        <input type='text' name='External' value='OEM/Non-OEM' style='background-color:#F9F9F9'>
        </label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function myFunction1() {
    var ex = document.getElementById("Calibrator").value;
        if (ex == "Internal"){
            external.style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            external.style.display = "block";           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show _proper_ [mre]s of issues like this. We don’t know what your PHP variables contain, so we can not tell what exact output this is going to produce either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to do something like this? One thing - I'm pretty sure that you cannot legitimately nest `label` elements as you do here if you wish to maintain valid HTML.
For the sake of the demo the PHP has been replaced with static values

```js
document.querySelector('select[name="Calibrator"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
    document.querySelector('label#external').style.display=this.value=='Internal' ? 'none' : 'block'
})
```

```html
<select name="Calibrator">                               
  <option value="Internal">Internal
  <option value="External">External
</select>

<br />
<label id="external" style="display:none">
<label>External (FOR EXTERNAL)</label>
<label style='margin-left:112px'>: </label> 
<input type='text' name='External' value='OEM/Non-OEM' style='background-color:#F9F9F9'>
</label>
```